# SSMSE version is suitable for MS SQL Server 2008 SP4 in Win 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010, sql-server

Can anybody know and provide the suitable version & download link of MS Management Studio for MS SQL Server 2008 SP 4 in win 8?

Am downloaded the SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU and when install it facing the Compatibility issues of MS Sql server 2008 and R2. There is no suggestion available comes when I click "Get online solution".

Other based product I have:

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2010 Ulimate - having .Net Framework 4
- Sp 4 for Sql server 2008 (KB2979596)

Comment: Set the compatibility mode to Windows 7, and if its going to work, it will otherwise considering switching to a later version of the Management Studio.

Comment: @RamHound If i create mdf file in management studio 2012 means, then can i use it in sql server 2008 SP 4?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SSMSE 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) (it's part of the SQL 2012 Express install package, there's no separate download just for SSMSE2012).

It's compatible with Windows 8 and [can manage SQL versions 2005 thru 2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0151c2e8-2281-4a78-86b0-20cc1bfd57ac/installing-sql-server-2012-management-studio-with-a-2005-database?forum=sqltools).